# Perform conditional assignment using Ruby reflection

Tags: ruby, reflection

In Ruby, I have a list of property names like the following:

```
names = [
  :foo,
  #...
]
```

I'd like to iterate through the list and, using reflection, perform conditional assignment on the property name. So, for example, rather than this, which doesn't use reflection:

`self.foo ||= 0`

I'd like something like something like this:

```
for name in names
   #use local variable "name" to perform assignment using reflection 
end
```

How can I achieve this using Ruby reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo.bar ||= baz
```

is *roughly* equivalent to

```
foo.bar || foo.bar = baz
```

It's not quite the same, but close enough for your purpose, I think. So,

```
names.each do |name| send(name) || send(:"#{name}=", 0) end
```

should do what you want. That is of course equivalent to

```
names.each do |name| send(:"#{name}=", 0) if send(name) end
```

which might be a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
names.each { |name| self.instance_variable_set("@#{name}", 0) }
```

will probably be a first approximation for what you need to do.

Comment: Can you describe how this is semantically similar or different to the equivalent `self.foo ||= 0`? For example, does it still use message-passing "send" semantics, or does it bypass them?

Comment: instance_variable_set will define the variable if it did not already exist.  So in effect this is property injection; if a property exists in the list of names you pass it that does not strictly belong, instance_variable_set doesn't care.  instance_variable_set is the fire-truck full of paint that some bastard just parked on your class' front lawn with the hose set to 'wide area' and the pump set to full speed... That is to say, instance_variable_set will happily change your class for you.

Comment: setting `self.foo` might be different from setting `@foo`

Comment: @ArieShaw true, but his use of the term property implies instance variables - or at least, that's how I understood it.